# How to get Facebook attribution ID on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook attribution ID is available if user installed Facebook app on his phone.

On Android, it can be extracted with this piece of code -
[Report Android app install back to facebook without using their api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126268/report-android-app-install-back-to-facebook-without-using-their-api)

By looking at Facebook's SDK for iOS, they access it with -

```
+ (NSString *)attributionID {
    return [[UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"fb_app_attribution" create:NO] string];
}
```

(https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBUtility.m)

But when I call this method on a phone with FB app installed, it returns `nil`.

How do I extract it on iOS?

Comment: Have you evere reached the goal?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I think the answer is that you can't do this. At least for as long as Facebook is using the UIPasteboard.

That code in your post would access an app-specific pasteboard. If it was created by the Facebook application then it would only be accessible to Facebook's other applications.

> The UIPasteboard class enables an app to share data within the app and
>   with another app. To share data with any other app, you can use
>   system-wide pasteboards; to share data with another app that has the
>   same team ID as your app, you can use app-specific pasteboards.

The quote above is from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html)